# Android Studio - Insistent Notifications on Oreo w/ Notification Channels

Tags: java, c#, android, notifications, channel

I am currently developing an app where insistent notifications are required. However, I can't seem to get them to work unless the app is open. Is there a way to get insistent notifications connected to the notification channel, even when the app is not open? I'm using a Windows Service to curl the notifications. I'm developing on Oreo. Thank you!